# Java Spring & MyBatis - How can I map "LEVEL" db column in XML file

Tags: spring, mybatis, oracle19c

I am a newbie in Java Spring and My Batis and I have a problem mapping the DB column that is a keyword in Oracle in MyBatis 3.4 XML file.

I am using Java Spring 2.2.11, Oracle 19C, and MyBatis 3.4.0.

**Mapper XML file:**

```
<resultMap id="regionResultMap" type="org.idashboard.entity.Region">
    <id column="code" property="code"/>
    <result column="parent_code" property="parentCode"/>
    <result column="ancestors" property="ancestors"/>
    <result column="name" property="name"/>
    <result column="level" property="level"/>
    <result column="sort" property="sort"/>
    <result column="remark" property="remark"/>
</resultMap>
```

**Generated SQL:**

```
SELECT code,
       parent_code,
       ancestors,
       name,
       level,
       sort,
       remark
  FROM region
 WHERE code = '110102';
```

**Error description:** `[Error] Execution (30: 8): ORA-01788: CONNECT BY clause required in this query block`

**The problem** occurs because I used `"LEVEL"` column in `region` table.

How can I solve this issue? And how can I use column names that are the keywords in Oracle?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT code,
       parent_code,
       ancestors,
       name,
       "level",
       sort,
       remark
  FROM region
 WHERE code = '110102';
```

In the case where you need to use keywords in query, oracle uses double quotes (") to identify the word as not a keyword. In mysql you will need to use backticks (`) for the same purpose.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I think we have two options in oracle

Firstly is the use of alias in Query but in this case doesn't solve anything for you because you mapped it with the name level in xml

Second you can use  double quotes (", eg "level"),in MySQL defaults is using backticks (`)